# Port scan returning all ports open on non-existent network machines

Tags: python, sockets, ip, ip-address, port-scanning

I'm doing a project for my course that involves creating a port scanner for IP addresses. It involves a user input for a network address that will then generate a list of addresses and a txt file for the ports. I've got it more or less working, but have noticed something strange that I can't explain or find an answer for.

Basically, when I'm testing the network I'm currently on (standard 192.168 home network) it seems to work as intended. It takes time to scan the port and reports whether they're open or closed. For example, my machine will return the correct ports being open while a non-existent machine will list all its ports as closed.

However, if I put in a different network (say 192.169.0.0) it instantly loops through all of the addresses reporting all ports are open, seemingly without scanning them. And that's what doesn't make sense to me, especially since the earlier non-existent machine returns closed as I'd expect.

I've tried googling it and searching around here but couldn't find an answer (one question went unanswered). This is the specific function I'm calling;

```
def sockCheck(x):
    for y in portList:
        try:
            location = (str(hosts[x]), int(y))
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            c = s.connect_ex(location)
            if c == 0:
                print("Port "+y+" open")
            else:
                print("Port "+y+" closed")
            print(" ")
            s.close()
        except:
            print("Port "+y+" unavailable")
            s.close()
```

I know it's not great (still learning). For reference, `portList` is the list of ports from the imported `port.txt` file and `hosts[x]` is how I'm looping through my generated IP addresses (that I need to individually check their ports).

I'll post other code if requested.

Comment: Not an answer but you should treat 'connection refused' as an open port. You got all the way into the operating system which found nothing listening at that port.

Comment: @user207421 that's the definition of a closed port.

Comment: For me the `connect_ex` takes a really long time and eventually returns 60 if I pass in a nonexistent address. What exactly happens could also depend on local firewall rules etc. Do you get the same symptom for every invalid address?

Comment: @tripleee Same thing happens for any non-existent network. If the network exists then it returns closed ports (so 192.168.x.x for my home network works fine) but any other address (e.g. 192.24.1.0) gives the all ports open thing. What I don't get is how it doesn't even seem to check, just instantly spits out "open" for all ports.

Comment: So do you have funky firewall rules in place, or a router which connects invalid connections to someplace warm and special?

Comment: @tripleee Nothing funky as far as I know/can see and honestly wouldn't know where the invalid connections go. I've always assumed they just get dropped.

Comment: @user253751 No, it is a open port. The firewall let the TCP SYN through to the operating system.

Comment: @user207421 ... no, it's the definition of a closed port. Have you ever used a port scanner? They don't scan firewalls, they scan IP addresses.